# How to use OR in IF, ELSE, THEN Condition - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Trying to write a IF, ELSE, THEN statement with a few conditions. Below is my vb.net code:

```
If AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Egan Jones" Or _
        AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Farient Advisors" Or _
        AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Glass Lewis" Or _
        AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Internal Guidelines" Or _
        AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "ISS" Or _
        AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "None" Then
            RunSql("insert into institution_has_policy (institution_id,policy_id) values (" & _
                    InstitutionID & "," & NewPolicyID & ")")
End if
```

Basically, I am trying to tell the program that if AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox does not equal to any of the names listed in the condition, then go ahead and save the new information into the Institution_has_Policy table.

However, every time I run it, it runs the FIRST IF condition, but skips the other 5.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Nothing is getting "skipped", this is a single statement as far as the debugger is concerned.  It will *never* highlight any of the other lines in the statement.

Comment: You are looking for AND not OR. Also, do not concatenate your parameter in the sql string. Use the [Prameter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `OR`, which means the if() test can bail out as soon as ANY of the conditions evaluate to boolean TRUE. e.g.

```
 FALSE or FALSE or FALSE or TRUE or FALSE .... FALSE = TRUE
```

If your `.Text` is NOT equal to "Egan Jones", then that's "true", and the rest of the statement becomes irrelevant and execution will skip straight into the 'true' clause.

You want `AND` instead.

```
TRUE and TRUE and FALSE and TRUE ... = FALSE
```

Comment: That's not correct, the short-circuit operator is OrElse.

Comment: Wait, AND operator works, but you're saying I should use OrElse instead?

Comment: no. orelse is wrong. you're doing multiple tests for inequality, but your text is going to be unequal to at least ONE thing in your list, which means the entire overall `if()` will evaluate to "true".

Comment: I tried both ways, OrElse will give me a FK CONSTRAINT error in regards to my database.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't answering your question directly, but you might want to try something cleaner and easier to read:

```
Dim badNames = New List(Of String) From { "Eagan Jones", "Farient Advisors", "Glass Lewis", "Internal Guidelines", "ISS", "None" }

if (badNames.Contains(AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text)) then
    ...
else
    ...
end if
```

Comment: Paul I like your (coding) style. I upvoted +1 from me

Comment: Agreed, this is the cleanest way to present what's going on. Also has the added benefit of being able to add or remove items to the list on the fly.

Comment: Looking at the OP's code, I believe a `NOT` operator would be preferred  since the the OP is looking to do something if it's not contained in the list. Added benefit; the `Else` statement can be dropped for even cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Try OrElse!

```
If AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Egan Jones" OrElse _
    AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Farient Advisors" OrElse _
    AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Glass Lewis" OrElse _
    AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "Internal Guidelines" OrElse _
    AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "ISS" OrElse _
    AdvisoryFirms.AdvisoryFirmNameTextBox.Text <> "None" Then
        RunSql("insert into institution_has_policy (institution_id,policy_id) values (" & _
                InstitutionID & "," & NewPolicyID & ")")
```